# Drawing a rectangle behind custom ImageView not animating

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas, custom-view

I need a custom Image View that first draws some shapes behind the image before it draws the image itself using the same "Scaling" applied to the actual bitmap itself. Everything is working great except I have an AlphaAnimation to fade the custom ImageView in. It fades the BitmapDrawable part but not my shape. The Shape is drawn in full opacity at all times. I have tried setting the alpha of the paint i'm using to the getAlpha of the view but with no luck. Here is my onDraw function inside my custom ImageView class:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] f = new float[9];
    getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

    final float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    final float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    final Drawable d = getDrawable();
    final int origW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int origH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();

    final int actW = Math.round(origW * scaleX);
    final int actH = Math.round(origH * scaleY);

    canvas.drawRect(Math.max((getWidth() - actW) / 2, 0) + 1, Math.max((getHeight() - actH) / 2, 0) + 1, Math.max((getWidth() - actW) / 2, 0) + actW - 1, Math.max((getHeight() - actH) / 2, 0) + actH - 1, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: final Drawable d = getDrawable(); d.setAlpha(1); for your shape drawable

Comment: This produces no change. I have found that onDraw() is only called once and not in every frame of the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for your problem will be to add the custom view to some sort of view container and then just animate the container instead.

Comment: This is a simple way to get it working properly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java/?v=source), version: 5.0.0_r1, of onDraw method of imageView

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (mDrawable == null) {
        return; // couldn't resolve the URI
    }

    if (mDrawableWidth == 0 || mDrawableHeight == 0) {
        return;     // nothing to draw (empty bounds)
    }

    if (mDrawMatrix == null && mPaddingTop == 0 && mPaddingLeft == 0) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        int saveCount = canvas.getSaveCount();
        canvas.save();

        if (mCropToPadding) {
            final int scrollX = mScrollX;
            final int scrollY = mScrollY;
            canvas.clipRect(scrollX + mPaddingLeft, scrollY + mPaddingTop,
                    scrollX + mRight - mLeft - mPaddingRight,
                    scrollY + mBottom - mTop - mPaddingBottom);
        }

        canvas.translate(mPaddingLeft, mPaddingTop);

        if (mDrawMatrix != null) {
            canvas.concat(mDrawMatrix);
        }
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no use of `Paint` in here, so I bet this is your problem. Try creating new `Paint` and set its alpha to [Drawable.getAlpha()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getAlpha())

Since Drawable.getAlpha() require API 19, you can wrap it in your own Drawable like this:

```
class MyDrawable extends Drawable {

    final Drawable originalDrawable;
    private int mAlpha = 1;

    @Override
    public int getAlpha() {
        return mAlpha;
    }

    public MyDrawable(Drawable drawable){
        originalDrawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        originalDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mAlpha = alpha;
        originalDrawable.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        originalDrawable.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return originalDrawable.getOpacity();
    }
}
```

Comment: I went through the Android code before posting. On my question I did say that I tried setting the alpha of my paint to getAlpha(). did not work. getDrawable().getAlpha() is minSDK 19 so can't use that either.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt unfortunately it does nothing. I even tried raising my min sdk just to test and use getDrawable().getAlpha(). Still doesnt fade the shape in. only the drawable.

Comment: Im guessing the AlphaAnimation doesn't actually set the alpha property. I even tried using a ViewPropertyAnimator

Comment: @MitchDart lol, this would be out of the scope of the question ;)

Comment: I found that throughout the entire animation, onDraw is only called once. That is why im experiencing this.